# FragmentTransaction.Replace causing white (blank?) screen in app

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin

The flow of my app is as follows:

MainActivity:
HomeFragment -> BlackoutSetupFragment -> BlackoutFragment -> HomeFragment

For some reason, when I try to go to the HomeFragment from the BlackoutFragment, the MainActivity becomes empty, and nothing is rendered until I leave the app and come back to it. On the left is what the HomeFragment normally looks like, and on the right is what it looks like when I navigate back to it:

[image]
[image]

The set of methods I am using to set the fragments:

```
    // Which is invoked like 
    // SetFragment(typeof(HomeFragment), "Home", true, true, false);
    public void SetFragment(Type fragmentType, string fragmentName, bool addToBackStack, bool showNavigationIndicator, bool useSlideAnimation)
    {
        if (fragmentType == typeof(HomeFragment))
            SetFragment(new HomeFragment(), fragmentType, fragmentName, addToBackStack, showNavigationIndicator, useSlideAnimation);
        else if (fragmentType == typeof(BlackoutFragment))
            SetFragment(new BlackoutFragment(), fragmentType, fragmentName, addToBackStack, showNavigationIndicator, useSlideAnimation);
        else if (fragmentType == typeof(BlackoutSetupFragment))
            SetFragment(new BlackoutSetupFragment(), fragmentType, fragmentName, addToBackStack, showNavigationIndicator, useSlideAnimation);
    }

    private void SetFragment(Fragment fragment, Type fragmentType, string fragmentName, bool addToBackStack, bool showNavigationIndicator, bool useSlideAnimation)
    {
        FragmentTransaction transaction = this.FragmentManager.BeginTransaction();

        if (useSlideAnimation)
            transaction.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animator.enter_from_left, Resource.Animator.exit_to_right, Resource.Animator.enter_from_right, Resource.Animator.exit_to_left);

        transaction.Replace(Resource.Id.content_main_fragment_layout, fragment, fragmentType.Name);

        if (addToBackStack)
            transaction.AddToBackStack(null);

        transaction.Commit();

        this.FragmentManager.ExecutePendingTransactions();

        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fragmentName))
            SetAppBarTitle(fragmentName);

        if (showNavigationIndicator) _navDrawerToggle.DrawerIndicatorEnabled = true;
        else _navDrawerToggle.DrawerIndicatorEnabled = false;
    }
```

and the axml for the main activity's content is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_main_fragment_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Anyone know what might be happening here? I tried to include everything that I thought would be useful here for debugging but if something else is needed, shoot me a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was using `System.Timers.Timer` in order to update the UI with a countdown on the BlackoutFragment. Replacing it with `System.Threading.Timer` seems to have resolved the issue. My guess is that the elapsed event "RefreshView", running on the UI thread, was causing some funkiness when trying to move away from the fragment.

So replacing:

```
    public override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        //...
        _refreshTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        _refreshTimer.Interval = 1000;
        _refreshTimer.Elapsed += RefreshView;
        _refreshTimer.Start();
    }

    public override void OnPause() 
    {
        base.OnPause();
        //...
        _refreshTimer.Dispose();
    }
```

with:

```
    public override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        //...
        _refreshTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(RefreshView, null, 0, 1000);
    }

    public override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        //...
        _refreshTimer.Dispose();
    }
```

resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't add the initial Fragment to the backstack, as that will cause it to be a reversible transaction. Meaning if your initial state is "no fragment", and you add a transaction for "no fragment" -> "HomeFragment" to the backstack, then you can pop back to the "no fragment" state.

Simply change the call for the initial Fragment so that it does not add it to the backstack.

Comment: I tried this and didn't have any luck. To make sure I wasn't doing something silly, I even commented out the portion of code that adds fragments to the backstack, and it still does the exact same thing when I set the fragment as HomeFragment.